# Como utilizar ajax e php pra chamar uma função em php?

Tags: php, ajax

Estou com dificuldade para realizar requisição de uma função PHP via Ajax

**Código AJAX:**

```
$.ajax({
   url:   'geraSenhaProvisoria.php',
   type:  'POST',
   cache: false,
   data:  {geraSenha(6, true, true, true)},
   error: function() {
         alert('Erro ao tentar ação!');
   },
   success: function( texto ) { 
         $("#senha_provisoria").val( texto );
         $("#senha_provisoria").removeAttr("disabled");
   },
   beforeSend: function() {
   }
});
```

**geraSenhaProvisoria.php**

```
 function geraSenha($tamanho = 6, $maiusculas = true, $numeros = true, $simbolos = false){
    $letrasMinuscula = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $letrasMaiuscula = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $numero          = "1234567890";
    $simbolo         = "!@#$%*-";
    $retorno         = "";
    $caracteres      = "";

    $caracteres .= $letrasMinuscula;
    if ($maiusculas){ $caracteres .= $letrasMaiuscula; }
    if ($numeros){    $caracteres .= $numero; }
    if ($simbolos){   $caracteres .= $simbolo; }

    $len = strlen($caracteres);
    for ($n = 1; $n <= $tamanho; $n++) {
    $rand = mt_rand(1, $len);
    $retorno .= $caracteres[$rand-1];
    }
    return $retorno;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você pode passar as variáveis para o php usando a propriedade `data` do ajax e então no próprio php verificar e fazer a chamada da função:

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'geraSenhaProvisoria.php',
  data: {
        geraSenha: "true",
        tamanho: "6",
        maiusculas: "true",
        numeros: "true",
        simbolos: "true"
  } /* ... */
});
```

php:

```
$geraSenha = $_POST['geraSenha'];
$tamanho = $_POST['tamanho'];
$maiusculas = $_POST['maiusculas'];
$numeros = $_POST['numeros'];
$simbolos = $_POST['simbolos'];

if ($geraSenha == "true"){
  geraSenha($tamanho, $maiusculas, $numeros, $simbolos);
}

geraSenha( /*...*/ );
```

Comment: adaptei aqui no meu código e funcionou perfeitamente, agradeço ajuda!vlw.

Comment: como ficou o seu por favor?

Answer (score 5):

Eu sempre uso assim, passando os parâmetros na url

```
        $.ajax({
        url: '/main/conciliacao/gera-senha/tam/6/mai/true/sim/true/num/true',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        datatype: "json",
        error: function() {
            alert('Erro ao tentar ação!');
        },
        success: function(texto) {
            $("#senha_provisoria").val(texto);
            $("#senha_provisoria").removeAttr("disabled");
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
        }
    });
```

Caso os parâmetros sejam variáveis a url ficaria assim

```
url: '/main/conciliacao/gera-senha/tam/<?php echo $tam ?>/mai/<?php echo $maiusculas ?>/sim/<?php echo $simbulos ?>/num/<?php echo $numeros ?>',
```

E a função fica assim

```
public function geraSenhaAction() {
        $tamanho = $this->params()->fromRoute('tam', 0);      
        $maiusculas = $this->params()->fromRoute('mai', 0);
        $numeros = $this->params()->fromRoute('sim', 0);      
        $simbolos = $this->params()->fromRoute('num', 0); 
        $letrasMinuscula = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        $letrasMaiuscula = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        $numero = "1234567890";
        $simbolo = "!@#$%*-";
        $retorno = "";
        $caracteres = "";

        $caracteres .= $letrasMinuscula;
        if ($maiusculas) {
            $caracteres .= $letrasMaiuscula;
        }
        if ($numeros) {
            $caracteres .= $numero;
        }
        if ($simbolos) {
            $caracteres .= $simbolo;
        }

        $len = strlen($caracteres);
        for ($n = 1; $n <= $tamanho; $n++) {
            $rand = mt_rand(1, $len);
            $retorno .= $caracteres[$rand - 1];
        }
        $json = json_encode($retorno);
        echo $json;  exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

A função geraSenha(...) não vai ser executada a menos que você chame ela pelo seu arquivo PHP. Até onde eu sei, não é possível chamar diretamente uma função PHP pelo jQuery.

Nesse caso, você irá fazer a chamada normalmente pelo ajax:

```
$.ajax({
   url:   'geraSenhaProvisoria.php',
   type:  'POST',
   cache: false,
   data:  "val1=6&val2=true&val3=true&val4=true",
   error: function() {
         alert('Erro ao tentar ação!');
   },
   success: function( texto ) { 
         $("#senha_provisoria").val( texto );
         $("#senha_provisoria").removeAttr("disabled");
   },
   beforeSend: function() {
   }
});
```

Depois no PHP você vai ter que primeiro adquirir essas informações e lá sim chamar a função.
Algo do tipo:

```
$val4 = $_POST['val1'];
$val3 = $_POST['val1'];
$val2 = $_POST['val1'];
$val1 = $_POST['val1'];

geraSenha($val1,$val2,$val3,$val4);

function geraSenha($tamanho = 6, $maiusculas = true, $numeros = true, $simbolos = false){
    $letrasMinuscula = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $letrasMaiuscula = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $numero          = "1234567890";
    $simbolo         = "!@#$%*-";
    $retorno         = "";
    $caracteres      = "";

    $caracteres .= $letrasMinuscula;
    if ($maiusculas){ $caracteres .= $letrasMaiuscula; }
    if ($numeros){    $caracteres .= $numero; }
    if ($simbolos){   $caracteres .= $simbolo; }

    $len = strlen($caracteres);
    for ($n = 1; $n <= $tamanho; $n++) {
    $rand = mt_rand(1, $len);
    $retorno .= $caracteres[$rand-1];
    }
    return $retorno;
}
```

Qualquer dúvida, só falar!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer algo assim:

JS

```
// ...
data: {
    funcao: 'geraSenha',
    parametros: [ 6, true, true, true ]
}
// ...
```

PHP

```
call_user_func_array($_POST['funcao'], $_POST['parametros']);
```

Neste caso, estou passando o nome da função a ser executada e seus parâmetros. No PHP basta eu passar estes dados para a função `call_user_func_array` ([doc](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.call-user-func-array.php)) para passar corretamente os parâmetros.

Vale lembrar que não fiz nenhuma verificação de segurança. Caso seu arquivo `geraSenhaProvisoria.php` seja utilizado apenas para executar a função `geraSenha`, você não precisa passá-la como parâmetro.

```
// ...
data: {
    parametros: [ 6, true, true, true ]
}
// ...

call_user_func_array('geraSenha', $_POST['parametros']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Dependendo do tamanho do seu sistema e da quantidade de funções que você tenha nele será necessário utilizar uma forma mais organizada de trabalhar com `Ajax/Php` executando funções, aqui vai algumas dicas:

Crie suas funções e após isto crie um `switch` com os cases desejados exemplo:

`PHP`:

```
function soma($a, $b) {
   return $a + $b;
}

switch ($_POST['ACAO']):
   case 'SOMA':
      $output = soma($_POST['A'], $_POST['B']);
      break;
endswitch;
json_encode($output);
```

`jQuery`:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'teste.php',
   data: 'ACAO=SOMA&' +'A=' + a + '&B=' + b ,
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function (data) {
      console.log(data); 
   },
   error: function (data) {
      alert(data);
   }
});
```

Dessa forma o seu `PHP` não sai executando tudo, ele entra no `switch` vai na opção selecionada e dps sai enviando para o ajax a resposta.

é bem básico mas espero que ajude.