# Atualizar variável php de uma pagina sem recarrega-la através de outra pagina formulário

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou fazendo um sistema de senha no qual o atendente poderá digitar o numero da senha e chamar um cliente através de um painel. O código que você me mandou funciona porém não do jeito que eu esperava.. Preciso atualizar uma página que estará em funcionamento através da outra pagina, preciso que o form enviei para ele mesmo e execute um evento na outra pagina que estará rodando

O código está funcionando porém preciso dar um F5 na pagina toda para que a variável atualize. preciso enviar algum evento para que atualize e execute um código em javascript que é um som.

Form no qual atualizo a variável:

```html
<?php
     session_start();
  
      if(!empty($_POST['senha'])){ 
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];
    $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
   }
   else 
    $senha = 0000; 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
         <input type=text name="senha"/>
         <button>Enviar</button>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Página que recebe a variável:

```html
<?php

session_start();

$senha = $_SESSION['senha'];
?>
<html>
<?php echo $senha; ?>
</html>
```

código som:

```js
 <script>
 function Senha(){
    var audio1 = new Audio();
    audio1.src = "sound/senha.mp3";
    audio1.play();
 }
 </script>
```

Obrigado desde já..

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como utilizar ajax e php pra chamar uma função em php?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49337/como-utilizar-ajax-e-php-pra-chamar-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-php)

Comment: Já dei uma lida nesse post porém não esclarece minha duvida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc precisa msm dar echo na `$senha` na pagina que recebe a variavel? Eu n sei o que vc pretende fazer com isso, mas talvez fosse melhor dar mais detalhes, o codigo abaixo processa o formulario e exibe o valor de `$senha` na mesma página do form, com Ajax.

php arquivo que recebe a variavel:

```
<?php
session_start();
$senha = $_SESSION['senha'];
echo json_encode(['senha' => $senha]);
?>
```

ajax:

```
<?php
 session_start(); 
  if(!empty($_POST['senha'])){ 
   $senha = $_POST['senha'];
   $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
  }
  else 
      $senha = 0000; 
?>
<html>
   <body>
      <form class="form_class" action="url do arquivo" method="post">
         <input type=text name="senha"/>
         <button class="button_class">Enviar</button>
      </form>
   <span class="senha"></span>
   </body>

<script>
$(".button_class").on("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault(),
    $.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url: "aqui vc coloca o url da arquivo que recebe a variabel $senha",
    data: $(".form_class").serialize(),
    success:function(data){
        var jsonSenha =JSON.parse(data);
        if($.trim(jsonSenha.senha)){
            $(".senha").html(jsonSenha.senha)
        }
    }
    })
})
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Amigo eu estou fazendo um sistema de senha no qual o atendente poderá digitar o numero da senha e chamar um cliente através de um painel.
O código que você me mandou funciona porém não do jeito que eu esperava..
Preciso atualizar uma página que estará em funcionamento através da outra pagina, preciso que o form enviei para ele mesmo e execute um evento na outra pagina que estará rodando. É possível ?

Comment: Sim, mas eu n estou mt familiarizado. Vc tem que criar uma `var` que seria: `var senha = $("aqui vc coloca a classe do input da senha q ta no form").val()` essa `var` vai pegar a senha que a pessoa digitou no form, mas tem que coloca ela dentro da funcao on click pra poder pegar o valor.

Comment: dps disso vc cria outra `var` pra poder enviar o valor com o ajax: `var senhaJson = {senha: senha}` (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) e coloca essa `senhaJson` no lugar do `$(".form_class").serialize()`. Aqui tem uns exemplos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168401/json-formatting-sending-json-via-jquery-ajax-post-to-java-wicket-server

Comment: e na pagina que vai receber a variavel vc usa a funcao `json_decode()` do php pra poder usar os valores que foram recebidos do form, e usa o jquery pra poder colocar o valor na tela sem ter que atualizar  a pagina. Essa parte é melhor vc da uma pesquisa pq eu n manjo mt disso, eu so fiz isso em websocket e foi com uma framework. Deve existir outras formas de se fazer isso mas esta além do meu conhecimento

Answer (score 0):

Somente com php, você não ira conseguir fazer isso. Não é possível uma pagina se comunicar com outra diretamente estando em maquinas diferentes. Mesmo na mesma maquina, não é possível através do php, somente através de JavaScript.

Uma das maneiras de você fazer isso é, o form que atualiza a senha armazena-la em um arquivo ou algo do gênero o que foi informado.
A pagina que representa o painel fazer uma requisição ajax de tempos em tempos para uma terceira pagina que retorna o valor atual armazenado no arquivo.

Simplificando teríamos os seguintes arquivos:

form_nova_senha.php -> É basicamente a sua pagina que ira atualizar a senha, porém ela deve armazena-la em algum lugar que seja acessível por outros requests, como um arquivo

painel.php -> Essa é a pagina que irá exibir a senha que foi armazenada pela pagina anterior. Aqui deve vir a lógica para disparar o ajax de tempos em tempos para o senha_atual.php. Caso a senha tenha mudado, toca o som.

senha_atual.php -> Retorna a senha que foi armazenada.